# pass NA values to raw and back

Tags: r, byte

I'm trying to implement something which concerns converting character strings to raw bytes back and forth. When looking at the behaviour of NA values I noticed that the following code always return "NA" and not NA in the first example below.

Hence my question. How can NA values be passed to raw to get them back as character later on?

```
rawToChar(charToRaw(as.character(NA)))
[1] "NA"
rawToChar(charToRaw("NA"))
[1] "NA"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you'll have to write your own `rawToChar` function:

```
myRawToChar <- function(x, ...) {
  naString <- charToRaw("NA")
  if (all.equal(x, naString)) {
    return(NA)
  }
  rawToChar(x, ...)
}
```

Now `myRawToChar(charToRaw("NA"))` will return `NA` instead of `"NA"`.

Comment: Thanks but myRawToChar(charToRaw("NA")) and 
myRawToChar(charToRaw(as.character(NA))) would both give NA. While I want them to return "NA" in the first case and NA in the second

Comment: That's impossible as their `byte` format is identical:
`charToRaw(as.character(NA)) == charToRaw("NA")`

Comment: The only alternative I see is digging into the internals and seeing if there are any `byte` values that are meaningless, and assigning NA to mean that. But that's a lot of work, will require a deep understanding of the Internals, digging into the underlying C code, and may be for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just redefine both `charToRaw` and `rawTochar` to make them handle missing values ?

```
myCharToRaw <- function(x,...) {
  if (is.na(x))  return(NA)
  charToRaw(x, ...)
}

myRawToChar <- function(x, ...) {
  if (is.na(head(x,1)))  return(NA)
  rawToChar(x, ...)
}
```

Then :

```
R> myRawToChar(myCharToRaw("NA"))
[1] "NA"
R> myRawToChar(myCharToRaw(NA))
[1] NA
```

Comment: thanks but I really need myCharToRaw to return a raw, not NA. is.raw(NA) give me FALSE.

Comment: I think it is just not possible. There doesn't seem to be NA value for raw type. `as.raw(NA)` raises an error, and there is no `NA_raw_` constant.

Comment: But I can do `is.na(as.raw(1:10))` or for characters: `is.na(do.call(c, lapply(LETTERS, charToRaw)))`. So why would is.na work on an object of class raw? Also `charToRaw(NA_character_)` works, it gives me the following raw vector: `[1] 4e 41`

Comment: I really don't think there is a NA value for raw type. and `4e 41` is just the raw conversion of `"NA"`.